# struct default values in c

Tags: c, struct, bit-fields

I came across this problem in C using structs.I'm not sure of what is really happening here
Thanks

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
 struct num1
 {
  int n1:2;
  int n2:3;
  int n3:4;
 };
 struct  num1 num={3,4,5};
 printf("%d %d %d\n",num.n1,num.n2,num.n3); 
 return 0;
}
```

The obtained output is

> -1 -4 5

Comment: Some combo of bitfields and, I suspect, UB.

Comment: See [Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)

Comment: how are (2,3,4) related to (3,4,5)

Comment: @wahid_abdul (2, 3, 4) are the length of the fields **in bits**. (3, 4, 5) are the values assigned to the fields. In `n1`, `n2`, those values are too big and overflow into the sign bit, resulting in `printf` showing the values as negative.

Answer (score 6):

These are bit fields, the number after the `:` specifies how many bits are in that member.

```
int n1:2
```

means a signed integer with 2 bits. In two's complement notation, this allows for values from `-2` to `1`; in sign+magnitude notation it allows for `-1` to `1`. When you try to assign `3` to this member, you get overflow, which results in undefined behavior.

Similarly

```
int n2:3
```

means a signied integer with 3 bits, whose range is `-4` to `3` in two's complement, `-3` to `3` in sign+magnitude, so assigning `4` causes overflow.

```
int n3:4
```

has a range from `-8` to `7` or `-7` to `7`, so assigning 5 fits into it, so there's no overflow.